# Android sharing generated code between test and androidTest

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I'm trying to share some code between my unit tests and my instrumentation tests. I've implemented something like the following in my build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    String sharedTestDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'
    test {
        java.srcDir sharedTestDir
    }
    androidTest {
        java.srcDir sharedTestDir
    }
}
```

This seems to work just fine for normal code. However, code that is generated from an annotation seems to produce problems in Android Studio only. (The code *runs* fine, but it produces red squiggles in Android Studio) Basically, Android Studio can't seem to find the generated classes for code that lives in src/sharedTest - even though the actual build is fine.

In case it's helpful, the generated classes are coming from Dagger (as I share a component/module between the two types of tests). I've got a custom Application object that lives in sharedTest which is where I notice the Android Studio error:

```
createApplicationComponent() {
    return DaggerMockApplicationComponent.create();
}
```

I've also added the apt command to both test and androidTest:

```
dependencies {
    testApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
    androidTestApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
}
```

I'm clearly missing something in my understanding around source sets here. Is there a cleaner way to share the code between test and androidTest? Is there a way to get Android Studio to see this generated code? Or, worst case, can I make Android Studio at least ignore this error more easily?

Comment: A long while later, but I think I can clarify exactly what's happening now. Android Studio gets unhappy with the fact that the generated code exists in two places (since the apt processor runs over the same file twice). So the problem isn't Android Studio not seeing the code - it's that it sees it *twice*.